# How to download file from URL and Alert user that file is downloaded successfully in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure, internet-explorer, url, azure-blob-storage

Problem Statement:

An Azure Microservice is sending [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) URL- "https://somestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/somecontainer/myfile.pdf", to the client web application.

- JavaScript should be able to download the file from the provided URL.
- When the file is successfully downloaded it should show the Alert.

My efforts:

- Able to download the file from url using following code in chrome and firefox, whereas IE is opening the file in the new tab and not downloading it.

  ```
              var link = document.createElement("a");
              document.body.appendChild(link); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
              link.download = fileName;
              link.target = "_blank";

              // Construct the uri
              link.href = dataUrl;
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();

              // Cleanup the DOM
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
              link.remove();
  ```
- Unable to proceed.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If you set the `content-disposition: attachment;` header, this should force a download.

Comment: The server here is Azure Storage account, and as mentioned I am only provided a Blob URL when I manually click on the URL on chrome, it gets downloaded. But in IE it gets opened in the new tab.

Comment: Is your code generating the download URL? In other words, do you control the code which generates the download URL.

Comment: No, the service is simply sending "BlobBlob" URL to the client.

Comment: Who owns the service - you or some 3rd party? And how is the service generating this URL? Can you share some code for that?

Comment: I own the service. It is not generating URL, it is simply creating a BlockBlob object, which contains the URL and it is passing the URL to the client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#download-blobs

Comment: Please take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933679/how-to-set-content-disposition-on-individual-azure-blob-requests. Essentially the trick is to create a SAS URL and set content-disposition property in the SAS. Once you do that, when you open up the link the file will always download.

Comment: Also, regarding your other requirement of alerting the user when a file is downloaded completely, I don't think it is possible to do that programmatically using JavaScript.

Comment: @GauravMantri Hey yes it worked, thanks a ton.

Comment: @GauravMantri : Can I delete blob once it is downloaded by the client? Actually the "Alert" is working for that only, when the download is completed, blob should be deleted. Help!

Comment: `Can I delete blob once it is downloaded by the client?` - Not automatically because you don't really know if the blob has been downloaded successfully.

Comment: Well yes, that is why I have asked about the way that, how to know if the file is downloaded completely in javascript. One thing more your solution with SAS is not working with chrome as it is downloading a html file and upon clicking on it, it then downloads the blob file. Strange!