# How to modify blob storage response header

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, content-disposition

Where can I update the response header to include "Content-Disposition" in the azure portal for blob storage? I only see the meta-data one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-and-retrieving-properties-and-metadata-for-blob-resources 
The above is the link I can find about setting properties and meta data. Dose azure even support modifying "Content-Disposition" in header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does azure even support modifying "Content-Disposition" in header?

You can certainly change `Content-Disposition` header property of a blob. It's just that Portal UI does not allow you to do that. You can use any available Storage Explorers (like Microsoft's Storage Explorer) to achieve the same or can change it programmatically as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's supported. Just it's an optional Request Header so it's not listed in the link you pasted.

So if you want to set the `Content-Disposition` header, you need use this `x-ms-blob-content-disposition`. About details you could find in this doc:[Set Blob Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties#request-headers-all-blob-types).

Comment: This should be the answer as it shows you how to set the response headers for all further responses without having to change them when each response is given.

Answer (score 0):

Please find more information on these headers at [Get Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) and use the Storage Explorer

You may also refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933679/how-to-set-content-disposition-on-individual-azure-blob-requests) thread, Here is the steps how you can try in [PS](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/accessing-properties-of-azure-blobs-with-powershell/) cmdlets

Additional information

```html
"name": "@replace(outputs('GetFileContents')['headers']['Content-Disposition'],'attachment; filename=','')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Logic Apps; you can use the connectors that allow you to host a publicly available endpoint, connect to Blob Storage, and modify your response headers.

[image: Logic App]