# How to download videos from Azure Blob Storage with a simple HTML link?

Tags: html, azure, video, download

I wanted to create a simple HTML link to be able to download a mp4 that was in a Azure Blob Storage container.

Just using the below HTML would create a link but when the link was clicked, the video would open in another tab and start to play.

```
<p>Click on the link to download the video:<p>

<p><a href="https://<your container name>/misc/ECM.mp4" download>ECM_video.mp4</a></p>
```

I didn't want the video to play but instead to force the video file to download to the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

To force the video file to download I had to change the Content Type for the video file in Azure from "video/mp4" to "file" by right-mouse button on the video file and clicking on Properties and then under the Properties tab.

[image]

Now the video file downloads to the user's computer using this HTML link

```
 <p>Click on the link to download the video:<p>

    <p><a href="https://<your container name>/misc/ECM.mp4" download>ECM_video.mp4</a></p>
```

Comment: While this works in your case, I don't think it's a great solution. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933679/how-to-set-content-disposition-on-individual-azure-blob-requests/45935771#45935771.